# Error in writing output file through AWK scripting

Tags: regex, awk, matching

I have a AWK script to write specific values matching with specific pattern to a .csv file.
The code is as follows:

```
BEGIN{print "Query Start,Query End, Target Start, Target End,Score, E,P,GC"}
/^\>g/ { Query=$0 }
 /Query =/{
    split($0,a," ")
    query_start=a[3]
    query_end=a[5]
    query_end=gsub(/,/,"",query_end)
    target_start=a[8]
    target_end=a[10]
    }
    /Score =/{
    split($0,a," ")
    score=a[3]
    score=gsub(/,/,"",score)
    e=a[6]
    e=gsub(/,/,"",e)
    p=a[9]
    p=gsub(/,/,"",p)
    gc=a[12]

    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",query_start, query_end,target_start,target_end,score,e,p,gc)
    }
```

The input file is as follows:

```
>gi|ABCDEF|

 Plus strand results:

 Query = 100 - 231, Target = 100 - 172
 Score = 20.92, E = 0.01984, P = 4.309e-08, GC =  51
```

But I received the output in a .csv file as provided below:

```
100 0   100 172 0   0   0   51
```

The program failed to copy the values of:
Query end
Score
E
P
(Note: all the failed values are present before comma (,))

Any help to obtain the right output will be great.

Best regards,

Amit

Comment: Why are you splitting based on space, use awks built in field separator.

Comment: **Hint:** `gsub` returns the number of substitutions made and **not** the modified string.

Comment: **Hint2:** `gensub` returns a modified string

Answer (score 2):

As @Jidder mentioned, you don't need to call split() and as @jaypal mentioned you're using gsub() incorrectly, but also you don't need to call gsub() at all if you just include `,` in your FS.

Try this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:],]+"
    OFS = ","
    print "Query Start","Query End","Target Start","Target End","Score","E","P","GC"
}
/^\>g/ { Query=$0 }
/Query =/ {
    query_start=$4
    query_end=$6
    target_start=$9
    target_end=$11
}
/Score =/ {
    score=$4
    e=$7
    p=$10
    gc=$13

    print query_start,query_end,target_start,target_end,score,e,p,gc
}
```

That work? Note the field numbers are bumped out by 1 because when you don't use the default FS awk no longer skips leading white space so there's an empty field before the white space in your input.

Obviously, you are not using your `Query` variable so the line that populates it is redundant.

Comment: Instead of using `,` in the field separator you could also leave it default and just use `+$N` to remove the commas.

Comment: @Jidder yeah (but `$N+0` for portability) but it's marginally more lengthy/complicated and I'm not sure what that'd do to a value like `4.309e-08,` on all awks so I prefer to just leave it as whatever strings were in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton Is `+$N` not portable ? It works with posix, i just tested as well and it seems to handle `4.309e-08,` fine and produce the same output.

Comment: @Jidder no, it wont work with nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk for example. It also has a precedence problem when used in some expressions (e.g. `print "x" +$N` vs `print "x" $N+0`). That's unrelated to what some awks might do with `4.309e-08` though.

Comment: Dear Jidder and Ed,
Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions and it worked excellently both in Linux and through GAWK in windows. Thanks a lot for your kind help once more.
I have another query:
1.If I have to run the same script (as provided by Jidder) for similar  multiple input files (in hundreds ) what additional changes should  be done to automate the process?

Comment: Dear Jidder ad Ed,
Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions and it worked excellently both in Linux and through GAWK in windows. Thanks a lot for your kind help once more.
I have another query:
1. If I have to run the same script (as provided by Jidder) for similar  multiple input files (in hundreds ) what additional changes should  be done to automate the process?

Comment: idk about a script Jidder provided but with mine there's no changes, just list all the files in the arg list or use `*` or whatever is used in Windows to generate files names.